# Showing that chromatic number of graph is sum of chromatic numbers of two disjoint subgraphs

Tags: coloring

Prove that for every graph $G$ on the vertex set V with at least one edge, there is a partition of $V = V_1 \cup V_2$
into two non-empty parts such that if $G(V_1)$ and $G(V_2)$ denote the graphs spanned by $G$ on the sets $V_1$
and $V_2$ respectively, than $χ(G(V1)) + χ(G(V2)) = χ(G).$

Comment: How far have you gotten with this?

Comment: @saulspatz My only idea is maybe induction on the the number of vertices of graph $G$. Otherwise, I'm not sure what approach to make

Comment: Suppose $G$ has been colored with $\chi(G)$ colors already.  Can you find appropriate $V_1,V_2$ now?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**HINT**
Suppose $G$ has been colored with $\chi(G)$ colors.  Let $V_1$ be the set of vertices that were colored with color $1$, and let $V_2=V\setminus V_1$.

Comment: None of the vertices in $V_1$ are adjacent, so they can be colored with the same color.

Comment: So do we have that $χ(G(V1)) = 1$, and that separately we have $χ(G(V2)) = χ(G)-1$?

Comment: That's it exactly.